# very simple sql select into a cursor has never worked for me

Tags: visual-foxpro, cursors

Been writing foxpro since 2.6 so 40 years. Never been able to get this to work. for umpteenth time searched web for hours but no luck. HELP!

```
Select * from mytable into cursor mycursor1 
select * from mycursor1 into cursor mycursor2
```

results:
mycursor1 contains the data from mytable as it should.
mycursor2 gets created (all the columns are there) but contains no data. it is always empty.

As I said in my comment, the above DOES work if done from native VFP command window. Here is pseudocode for what does NOT work. I use the VFE framework.

Create a view named mycursor1
This view is never queried. It is semi permanent meaning it is created when the user comes into my Point-Of-Sale screen and released when they leave. While in the POS screens the contents of this view is displayed in a grid. As items are sold I use VFE business objects to add the items to this view and they are shown in that grid. When the user finishes ringing up a sale, I  loop thru the view moving the contents of the view to another view (basically scan...replace statements...endscan but I do that with VFE business object commands). Then the data is saved from that 2nd view. Mycursor1 gets emptied (VFE's bo.cancel(.t.) so it is ready to ring up another sale. This part has worked flawlessly for over 30 years and is superfast.

I am inserting some new code just before I move the data from mycursor1 to the 2nd view for saving. That new code does an SQL Select (my database is all native VFP), so Select * from the view named mycursor1 into cursor mycursor2. This where the issue arises. As I said before, I am stepping thru the code. I see the 5 records in mycursor1. Mycursor2 gets created and contains all the fields from mycursor1 but mycursor2 is empty.

I believe this is happening because mycursor1 never get queried and is loaded from code/business objects instead of from VFP via a requery. I am going to do some testing today to see if I can prove that. I will post my results.

Gia has suggested other ways to move the data from mycursor1 to mycursor2. I do not believe that will accomplish my need. Why? I do not need to simply move the data from mycursor1 to mycursor2. When a sale is rang up in my POS screens, it contains rows something like +1 Snickers Bars then +3 Hershey Bars then -1 Snickers Bars, so 3 rows in mycursor1. The reason I am using an SQL select to move the data from mycursor1 to mycursor2 is to use a GROUP BY so that mycursor2 contains the contents of mycursor1 except grouped by item thereby getting rid of the minus (voids). So in this example I would end up with just 1 row in mycursor2 of +3 Hershey Bars. Hope that makes sense.

Thanks, John

Comment: When I start a Vfp9SP2 IDE session and run your proposed 1st line `Select * from mytable into mycursor1 && I get "Syntax error" (Error 10)`

Comment: Same when I run three lines instead of one `CD d:\temp` and then `CREATE TABLE mytable (col1 Int)` and then your proposed `Select * from mytable into mycursor1 && again "Syntax error" (Error 10)
`

Comment: Do you have a more or less minimal repro for us by chance?

Comment: Sorry Stefan, I edited the original post. It should have been "into cursor mycursor1".  BUT, it still doesn't work meaning the results are the same meaning mycursor2 gets created but does not get loaded.  A little more information: The code that I presented DOES work if done from the native VFP command window. My example was an attempt to describe a simplified version of the issue I am having. I have edited the original post to add what is NOT working. Thanks, John

Comment: I don't use VFE so I have no idea for parts related to it. As per your select commands, would you try by adding NOFILTER.

Comment: @vfpjohn , Cetin's answer is useful as always, isn't it, and I had not known the _umpteenth_ term before, let alone 'Viola' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your notes I noticed you were talking about a view. Views are buffered by default and in your case you might have it table buffered. In that case your select from that view wouldn't return any rows, unless you add WITH (BUFFERING=.T.) clause.

Here is a code piece that would simulate what might be happening:

```
SET MULTILOCKS ON
SELECT * FROM _samples+'data\customer' WHERE .F. INTO CURSOR cursor1 READWRITE 
CURSORSETPROP("Buffering",5,'cursor1')
APPEND FROM customer
browse

SELECT * FROM cursor1 INTO CURSOR cursor2 && No rows
*SELECT * FROM cursor1 WITH (buffering=.T.) INTO CURSOR cursor2 && has rows
browse
```

Comment: Cetin, after reading up on the with buffering clause, it sounded like that is exactly what is occuring. I checked just after I created the view: MULTILOCKS is ON and Buffering is set to 5. I added the WITH (buffering=.T.)  clause to my SQL select statement. I still do not get any data in cursor2.

Comment: Cetin, It turns out you WERE correct. While trying several variations I had modified my SQL select to say "FROM <my views database name>!mycursor1" instead of just "FROM mycursor1". I changed that back to "FROM mycursor1" and VIOLA!, it works perfectly. THANK YOU SO MUCH! John